# R - Create data frame which checks for NAs in multiple data frames

Tags: r, time-series, compare, na

I have two data frames such as

```
df1 <- data.frame(Company = c('A','B','C','D','E','F'),
                  `X1980` = c(21,NA,53,57,11,26),
                  `X1981` = c(35,33,45,NA,NA,12))
df2 <- data.frame (Company = c('A','B','C','D','E','F'),
                   `X1980` = c(78,2,NA,24,25,26),
                   `X1981` = c(435,33,45,5,10,12))
```

I would like to create a new data frame (df3) keeping the company column as is. The values for the years 1980 and 1981 should be 0 if either one or both values are NA and 1 if both values are not NA.
Resulting in the following data frame:

```
result df3
        Company  1980  1981
           A       1     1
           B       0     1
           C       0     1
           D       1     0
           E       1     0
           F       1     1
```

I'm new here, so if there's any way I can improve my question then just let me know :)
Thanks already for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a one-liner.

```
cbind(df1[1], (!is.na(df1[-1]) & !is.na(df2[-1])) + 0L)
#  Company X1980 X1981
#1       A     1     1
#2       B     0     1
#3       C     0     1
#4       D     1     0
#5       E     1     0
#6       F     1     1
```

**Data, corrected**

```
df1 <- data.frame(Company = c('A','B','C','D','E','F'),
                  `1980` = c(21,NA,53,57,11,26),
                  `1981` = c(35,33,45,NA,NA,12))
df2 <- data.frame (Company = c('A','B','C','D','E','F'),
                   `1980` = c(78,2,NA,24,25,26),
                   `1981` = c(435,33,45,5,10,12))
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick help and sorry about the mistake in the original question :)

Comment: @ConnorUhl Note the column names. In R, names must start with an alphabetic character unless you set argument `check.names = FALSE` when creating the data frame.

Comment: Thanks again! I've changed it in the original question.